# Angularjs post to Django Rest Framework API

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, rest, post

I'm sending  a post from an angular app to a Django Rest Framework API,  but when I receive the data, the `Querydict` is malformed, it's wrapped arround a dict, because that,when I try to save it, DRF cant find any field.

This is my post. `this` is an javascript object

```
return $http.post('/api/activities/'+activity_id+'/calendar/',this);
```

Im getting this `querydict`

```
    data  = request.DATA
    print data
    >> <QueryDict: {u'{"initial_date":1424118992563,"closing_sale":1424205392563,"capacity":1,"sessions":[],"number_of_sessions":0,"last_sn":0,"activity":1}': [u'']}>
```

Comment: Can you show rest of your view? Especially what parsers do you use?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a serializer.

```
my_serializer = DataSerializer(data=request.DATA)
if my_serializer.is_valid():
    print my_serializer.data
else:
    print serializer.errors
```